# Paxos: What happens if the leader lost connection after commit in his own ledger but before multicast the success message?

Tags: paxos

From the ***The Part-Time Parliament*** essay, what happens with the following situation.

The leader receives *Voted(b, q)* message from the majority and writes this degree
in his own ledger, but lost connection before sending the *Success(d)* message.

with the **Basic Protocol**:

1. The new leader will re-proposes this decree but with a different ballot number (*b+1*)
2. The older leader reconnects after the new proposal passed
3. Now, we have the same decree passed twice with *b* and *b+1*

with the **Multi-Decree Parliament**

1. The new leader first fill the gap of *b* with *no-op* and then re-proposal the decree
   with *b+1*
2. After the old leader reconnects, *b* is associated with two values:
   the decree in old leader's eye and *no-op* in others' eye

What's wrong with my thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

There is this statement in the essay: "The protocol’s requirements and assumptions were essentially the same as those of the later Parliament except that instead of containing a sequence of decrees, a ledger would have at most one decree."

The idea is that the ledger record number and ballot number - these are not same numbers. Each ledger number (each ledger position) may have more than one ballot to happen.

In your Basic Protocol example: there is a ledger with zero or one decrees. Even if the leader outage happens after consensus is reached - the final decree is still the same.